# $\lim \limits_{r \to 1} \frac{k - \frac{N(1-r^k)}{1-r^N}}{r-1} = -\frac{1}{2}k(k-N)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{k-\frac{N(1-r^k)}{1-r^N}}{r-1}=-\frac{1}{2}k(k-N)$$

I've found this limit to be tricky. Everytime I take the derivative to apply l'Hopital's rule I get an indeterminant fraction again. But yet the symbolic solver says the limit exists.

Comment: There is a typo in your title, it should be $\frac12 k(N-k)$.

Comment: need the following two identities to complete:  $1-r^n = (1-r)\left(\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(r^i)\right)$ and $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{N-1} n = \frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$

Comment: Yes these are both true, aren’t you familiar with that?

Comment: Refer also to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\frac{k - \frac{N(1-r^k)}{1-r^N}}{r-1}=\frac{ k(1-r)(1+r+\ldots+r^{N-1}) -  N(1-r)(1+r+\ldots+r^{k-1) } }{(r-1)(1-r^N)}=$$

$$=\frac{k(1+r+\ldots+r^{N-1})-N(1+r+\ldots+r^{k-1})}{r^N-1}=$$

and by l'Hopital

$$\frac{k(1+2r+\ldots+(N-1)r^{N-2})-N(1+2r+\ldots+(k-1)r^{k-2})}{Nr^{N-1}}$$

$$\to \frac{k\frac{N(N-1)}{2}-N\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}{N}=\frac12\left(kN-k-k^2+k\right)=\frac12k(N-k)$$

Answer (score 1):

Using standard notation for [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Notation), we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{
    f'(1) \left(g(r) - g(1)\right) - g'(1)\left(f(r) - f(1)\right)}{
    (r - 1)\left(g(r) - g(1)\right)}
&= \frac{
    f'(1)g[r,1,1]-g'(1)f[r,1,1] }{
    g[r,1]} \\
\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{
    f'(1) \left(g(r) - g(1)\right) - g'(1)\left(f(r) - f(1)\right)}{
    (r - 1)\left(g(r) - g(1)\right)}
&= \frac{f'(1)g''(1)-g'(1)f''(1) }{2 g'(1)} \\
\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{
    k \left(r^N-1\right) - N\left(r^k -1\right)}{
    (r - 1)\left(r^N-1\right)}
&= \frac{kN(N-1)-Nk(k-1)}{2N}\text{,}
\end{align}$$

and therefore

$$
\lim_{r\to 1} \frac{
    k \left(r^N-1\right) - N\left(r^k -1\right)}{
    (r - 1)\left(r^N-1\right)}
= \frac{k(N-k)}{2}\text{.}
$$

Comment: @pico: the equalities are correct as I have written them. To understand where the $r-1$ in the denominator "went", think through what $f[r,1,1]$ and $g[r,1,1]$ in the first equality mean, and consider how the left side can be rearranged to make $f[r,1,1]$ and $g[r,1,1]$ appear.